# Is there any drawbacks of using Apache Kafka with python instead of Java?

Tags: java, python, apache-kafka

I am developing an application in python and I have to use Apache-Kafka. I am very new to Kafka.

I read that python does not support transactional producer/consumer of Kafka. I just wanna know that will this flaw make any huge difference because of which I have to convert my python application to java and then use Kafka? Also is there any other drawback of using Kafka-python?

Comment: [Transactions in Apache Kafka](https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/) is an article that talks about how transactions in Kafka work, and the kinds of problems they are designed to solve. If you don't need to solve any of those problems, then you don't need transactions. If you think you might have those problems in the future, then you might want to plan ahead and use a Kafka client that supports transactions.

Comment: Thank you @dnault. I got your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually confluent-kafka’s python library uses [librdkafka](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka) underneath and as of latest version it does support exactly once semantics so no worries about that. For my knowledge there is no practical limitations of using python client but official java client has battery of features regarding stream support and custom partitioners(for producers) and other features so if you have a choice or you think python apps performance won’t be enough that start with java otherwise there are no drawbacks.

You can find a nice comparison of official clients [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/index.html).

Comment: Still I have a question that this differentiation in the given link shows that python dose not support Kafka streams then how python can be use for Kafka streaming? May be I am not getting it. Can you please clarify this point? @YamYamm

Comment: sorry I have only used Java client for streams applications.

Comment: Not all Python Kafka libraries use librdkafka

Comment: Official python client are based on librdkafka, unofficial libraries may implement wire protocol natively.